# Android подключение к VPN по протоколу IPSec

Tags: android

Появилась задача на подключение к серверу по протоколу IPSec, в наличии из параметров адрес сервера, логин, пароль, общий ключ IPSec и идентификатор IPSec (VPN_GROUP).

Каким способом можно это реализовать программно?